# Joining 4 Tables in a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have four tables and I need to get data from all of them through a stored procedure.
Table 1 is the main table and is laid out like this

```
ID  REF1  REF2  Data1
 1   01    11    abc
 2   01    22    def
 3   01    33    ghi
```

Table 2 looks like this

```
ID  ref2ID  Data2
 1    11     a
 2    99     x
```

Table 3

```
ID  ref3ID  Data3
 1    22     b
```

Table 4

```
ID  ref4ID  Data4
 1    33     c
```

How would I get the data from all four tables based on the 'REF2' column.

I tried something like this, but I don't get the right data. I need to bring all the records on Data1, Data2, Data3 and Data4 column

```
Select Table1.Data1,
       Table2.Data2,
       Table3.Data3,
       Table4.Data4,
From   Table1 INNER JOIN
       Table2 ON Table1.REF2 = Table2.Ref2ID INNER JOIN 
       Table3 ON Table1.REF2 = Table3.Ref3ID INNER JOIN
       Table4 ON Table1.REF2 = Table4.Ref4ID
WHERE  REF1 = "01"
```

What am I doing wrong? please help

Comment: Maybe you want a left join instead of an inner join...but that is a guess without more info

Comment: I suspect you want a LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN. Are there records in Table1 that do not have corresponding rows in Table2, Table3 or Table4? Do you want to see the Table1 rows regardless? In that case, use LEFT OUTER JOIN

Comment: Thank you Melanie... yes I need data from table 1 too.. I am trying your suggestion now

Comment: According to your sample data, there isn't a way to join to `Table 3` or Table 4. You can only join Table 1 and Table 2.

Comment: @Icarus Table 1 REF2 column = Table3 ref3ID.. wouldn't that be possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `LEFT JOIN`s in this case, amd also use single quotes for strings:

```
SELECT Table1.Data1,
       Table2.Data2,
       Table3.Data3,
       Table4.Data4
FROM   Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 
    ON Table1.REF2 = Table2.Ref2ID 
LEFT JOIN Table3 
    ON Table1.REF2 = Table3.Ref3ID 
LEFT JOIN Table4 
    ON Table1.REF2 = Table4.Ref4ID
WHERE  REF1 = '01'
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/21b99/1) with a demo for you to try.